# Batch file to edit Registry value?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to edit the Registry value using a batch file, this is what I currently have:

```
 @echo off

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /v "1" /t REG_SZ /d "DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders" /f

pause
```

This is what I'm trying to edit:
       [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ Explorer]

```
   DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders   REG_DWORD    0x00000001
```

I want to set the value to 1 (0x00000001)  (By default it's 0x00000000)
But my cmd file creates another value named  DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders .
What did I do wrong?

Comment: The keys are like directories. The values (`/v`) are like filenames, e.g. `DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders`. The types (`/t`) are like filename extensions, e.g. `REG_DWORD`. And the data (`/d`) in this case is `1`.

Answer (score 9):

You have a couple problems.

1. The `/v` parameter is the value *name*, in your case `DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders`, and the `/d` parameter should be the actual value.
2. It looks like `DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders` is a `REG_DWORD`, but you are specifying it as `REG_SZ` with the `/t` parameter.

Try this command:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /v "DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```